# Best way to add exceptions in jquery selectors paths

Tags: jquery, events, css-selectors, custom-exceptions

let say i want to bind all items that are under

```
#mainDiv .user
```

Except

```
#mainDiv #exception .user
```

I can think of

```
$('#mainDiv .user').bind('event',function(){
    if($(this).parents('#exception').length>0){}else{
       // do stuff;   
    }

});
```

or:

```
$('#mainDiv :not('#exception').find('.user').bind('event',function(){
    if($(this).parents('#exception').length>0){}else{
       // do stuff;   
    }

});
```

Whats a better one?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I might suggest instead something like

```
$('#mainDiv .user').not('#mainDiv #exception .user').bind('event',function()
{
    //do stuff
});
```

the not() function takes a previously existing jquery set and removes the elements from within it that qualify for the selector that's passed in as a parameter.

filtering the pool up front is cleaner and more performant (probably doesn't matter, but it's good practice) than having both a selector and an if statement, and once you've filtered, the if statement is unnecessary.

as a side note, filtering for "#mainDiv #exception .user" seems kind of odd to me.  "#exception" should be a unique identifier all its own - unless you're concerned that for some reason "#mainDiv" might be a child of "#exception".

Answer (score 2):

First get all the elements, then remove the ones that you want to exclude:

```
$('#mainDiv .user').not('#mainDiv #exception .user').bind('event', function(){
  // do stuff
});
```

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet, Actually 2.. No, but I was just kidding :)

Answer (score 0):

I would delegate the event:

```
$( '#mainDiv' ).on( 'event', '.user', function () {

    if ( $( this ).parent().is( '#exception' ) ) { return; }

    // do your thing

});
```

You could also make a `this.parentNode.id === 'exception'` check...

Comment: but that would be same selection than mi first option but with just a different triggering... no?

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet I delegate the event, which is better than binding the handler to all elements...

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: That depends. It's not always better, as delegate has more runtime overhead than a simple bind.

Comment: @Guffa I meant better as in more proper. When you have multiple elements of the same class that share the same event handler, it is more proper to bind the handler *once* on the parent/ancestor then to bind it on each element individually.